Toilet seat is not clipping on properly
Toilet seat for a brand new toilet installation is clipping on but not locking in place.
It is a RAK Ceramics (UAE) Moon Wall Hung toilet and seat. I have an exact toilet in another bathroom, and strangely enough the bolt seems to be in a better condition, but similar, and is locked in place. I tried giving that seat a tug but it didn't come off, I didn't force anything to avoid breaking it. https://imgur.com/a/OfRKzrJ
There are two rods at the bottom the wall hung toilet, seems to be roughly under the seat bolts. The rods can go up and down and rotated, still not sure if it's related. https://imgur.com/a/99XAqdz
I don't see any bolts to tighten anywhere, any suggestions?


The hinge on the seat looks pitted and scratched, and the bolt on the toilet looks old.  What exactly is new, what is old, what model did you buy, where are the instructions?  Very vague guidance: Clips like that sometimes have a button or clip you have to push or pull to make or break the connection.  Usually they are not modular, IE, if the part bolted to the toilet is much older than the part in the seat, they may not fit together.

It should all have been new, the scratches might have been caused by the toilet seat moving as it's not installed properly.
The bolt was indeed rusted, maybe the plumber used some old bolts he had lying around.

The rods underneath are designed to prevent the nut (under the toilet) from turning when you tighten the upper part.  So you can tighten the bolt, without the seat, with one hand from above, and then "quick release" (snap) the seat on.  Only question is how the quick release operates.

Possibly with your thumb you push this thing this way to unlock the clip.  Just a guess.  You can probably do one at a time.
If that's how it works you probably have to loosen the pegs slightly from the toilet, install the seat without the locks (just reset the seat on the pegs), to get the pegs in the right position, then carefully remove the seat, tighten the pegs without moving them, and then install the seat with the clip locks.  This is based on a seat I've installed from a different manufacturer but with the same general idea.


Unfortunately, this part seems to be for aesthetic reasons and does not move, this is the mechanism from behind https://imgur.com/a/7DVc5Q0

Another possibility: the set can slip onto the pin when it is partially raised.  Try pushing down on the hinge while slowly lowering the seat and lid together from full up to full down.  At some point it may slip fully onto the pin.
